# One of my objects obstructs the others in solid mode

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I'm creating a donut in Blender.

**Problem:** In Solid mode, I'm not able to see the sprinkles of the donut. However, in the Material and Rendered modes I am able to see them. How do I see the sprinkles in the Solid mode too?

For example, here's the **Material mode** preview:

[image]

And, here's the **Solid mode** preview: *Can't see the donut's sprinkles!*

[image]

Comment: go into the bun object properties (orange ish square in the properties editor) and uncheck "In Front" if it is on

Comment: Thank you so much — it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the bun object properties (orange ish square in the properties editor) and uncheck "In Front" if it is on.

[image]